# RemoveAll from List

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove several items from a List which match a specific condition before I add the contents to a ListBox. I want anything which is (enum) "MediaState.Deleted" removing from the list.

So far I have tried:

```
//does not remove anything
        dbAssetList.RemoveAll(x => x.MediaState.Equals(6));     

    //Error on .equals which states that "Cannot access static method equals in non-static context"
        dbAssetList.RemoveAll(x => x.MediaState.Equals(typeof(MediaState),MediaState.Deleted));     

    //Error on .equals which states that "Cannot access static method equals in non-static context"    
        dbAssetList.RemoveAll(x => dbAssetList.Contains(x.MediaState.Equals(typeof(MediaState), MediaState.Deleted)));
```

What am I doing wrong, how can remove items in my list which are "MediaState.Deleted"

Comment: Have you tried `dbAssetList.RemoveAll(x => x.MediaState == MediaState.Deleted);`?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with `RemoveAll` and everything to do with comparing enums.

Comment: Rather than removing items from a list before adding the contents to a list box, why don't you add only those items that you want? `listBox.Items.Add(dbAssetList.Where(x => x.MediaState != MediaState.Deleted));`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper no... and that worked. Sometimes the simplest fixes are the hardest. Please add as a answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @RogerLipscombe The list is created and passed from a larger backing class which serves other code, otherwise I would do that. Thanks

Comment: @Damo: Done, with some extra explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first variant of your code does not remove anything because `Equals` will always return `false`:

According to the [docs of that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bafh2by.aspx), the return value is:

> `true` if `obj` is an enumeration value of the same type and with the same underlying value as this instance; otherwise, `false`.

If you pass the literal `6` to `Equals`, the conditions for `true` are not fulfilled, als `6` is of type `int`, not of type `MediaState`.

The other two variants are resolved by the compiler to the [static `Equals` method provided by `System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) (as it is the nearest `Equals` method with two parameters). The compiler will not compile that as you do not call that static method on `System.Object`, but on a reference typed to one of the subclasses thereof. As static methods are not resolved based on the current type pointed to by a variable, but at compile-time, such a call will not compile.

Instead, just use

```
listBox.Items.Add(dbAssetList.Where(x => x.MediaState != MediaState.Deleted));
```

The `==` operator for comparisons works well with enum values in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbAssetList.RemoveAll(x => x.MediaState.Equals(MediaState.Deleted));
```

or

```
dbAssetList.RemoveAll(x => x.MediaState == MediaState.Deleted);
```

.Equals(6) won't match any items in the list. The typeof() versions of Equals are static and can't be used in that context.